# Bootstrap panel title, div on left and right, horizontally aligned

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I change this, so that the title **Users** and the **Show  entries** are aligned on the same row. **Users** on the left and **show** on the right.

https://jsfiddle.net/PHPMickB/rbnd1yvh/1/

I tried putting them in the same div, then:

```
.dataTables_length {
    float:right;
}

#table-title{
    float:left;
}
```

But that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

To put the second panel along the right edge you can use `position:absolute;` Absolute positioning removes elements from the flow so no need to use display:inline-block like my previous answer. Just be sure to use `position:relative` on the parent.

```
.panel-heading{
  position:relative;
}

#users_length{
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

[here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbnd1yvh/24/)

Comment: That's great, nearly there but I actually want the #users_length on the right side of the header.